# OpenGL error: unrecognized layout identifier `binding'

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, sdl

my fragment shader

```c
#version 330
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer TVertex
{
   mediump vec4 vertex[]; 
};
```

results in

```
error: unrecognized layout identifier `binding'
```

I'm using SDL on ubuntu with

```c
SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3 );
```

which gives me

```
Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2) 
4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the binding point inside the shader is only supported starting with version 4.2, your shader is specified to use verrsin 3.3. See [the docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_buffer_output)
Either you change your version to `#version 420`.
Or you set the binding point inside your application with

```c
GLuint bindingPoint = 0;
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, bindingPoint, bufferObject);
```